# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a "BlocName"

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have an issue when using **MultiBlocProvider**, and passing the blocContext through the widgets.
I have in ShopScreen a MultiBlocProvider, and inside it a filter button, which shows a categories list from a ModalBottomSheet. like this:

[image: modalBottomSheet]

I have to update the shop screen when I choose a different category from the list.
So, I have this BlocConsumer wrapped with the Filter Button, and I have to pass the context to the modalBottomSheet, so I used BlocProvider.value -which show me this error when I press on the filter button-
[image: error]:

**My Multi Bloc Provider:**

```
  MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ProductsBloc>(create: (_) => productBloc),
        BlocProvider<CategoryBloc>(create: (_) => CategoryBloc()),
        BlocProvider<BannerBloc>(
            create: (_) => BannerBloc()..add(ShowBannerEvent())),
      ],
```

**The FilterButton**

```
 BlocConsumer<CategoryBloc, CategoryStates>(
                    builder: (context, cateState) {
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
                                  value:
                                      BlocProvider.of<CategoryBloc>(context)
                                        ..add(ShowCategoryEvent()),
                                  child: CategoryBottomSheet()),
                              isScrollControlled: true);
                        },
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 50.h,
                          width: 50.w,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'assets/fillter_button.svg', ),),);
                    },
                    listener: (context, cateState) {
                      if (cateState is CategorySelectedState)
                        widget.categoryId = cateState.categoryId;
                    },
                  ),
```

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a bloc, you should use `context.read<CategoryBloc>()`.

So for example:

```
context.read<CategoryBloc>().add(ShowCategoryEvent());
```

Comment: where should I add this line? when I added it in the Value it give 'void' doesn't conform to the bound 'BlocBase<Object?>' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'BlocBase<Object?>'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass Blocs from app context to ModalBottomSheet context.

Use `BlocProvider.value` function.

ModalBottomSheet context doesn't inherit data from application context automatically, you have to do this yourself.